# JSONString: expectedClass:NSDictionary error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am getting the error code 3840 in the following code.

```
- (id)unserializeJSONString:(NSString *)JSONString expectedClass:(Class)expectedClass {

 NSLog(@"unseralizab JSONString %@ and expected class %@",JSONString,expectedClass );
            if (!JSONString) {
                return nil;
            }
            NSError *error = nil;
        //    id JSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&error];
            id JSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

            if (!JSONObject || (expectedClass && ![JSONObject isKindOfClass:expectedClass])) {
                NSLog(@"JSONString:%@ expectedClass:%@ error:%@", JSONString, expectedClass, error);
            }
            return JSONObject;
        }
```

and following is the error I am getting

```
JSONString: expectedClass:NSDictionary error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x174261240 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}
```

What is going wrong in the above code.

Comment: Update your question with the complete error.

Comment: @rmaddy updated the question with the complete error .. It would be great if u can help me find the problem

Comment: Please post the json you want to deserialize, maybe it is wrong (no value)

Comment: I was able to reproduce this error by calling the Alamofire (AFNetworking for Swift) .POST method multiple times. It is definitely Alamofire/AFNetworking related but ATM I can't point my finger where exactly.